# Using awk variables to remove files

Tags: linux, unix, ksh, aix

```
#!/bin/ksh
grep -v "root" /MCS/usr/dbl/tsk/idle.txt | MESTAID=`awk ' {print $1}'`
grep -e "$MESTAID" MCSTNM.SAV | TTF=`awk ' {print $2}'`
```

for this example lets say `$TTF = 123 555 666`

The above grabs the user's 3 digit unique `TTF` number which I then need to delete using the following syntax: `rm /path_to_file/TT123.*`

However when I attempt to do it in the script: `rm /path_to_file/TT$TTF.*`

It tries to issue the following command: `rm /path_to_file/TT123 555 666.*`

Is there a way to take the `$TTF` variable and have it run independently ie:

```
rm /path_to_file/TT123.* 
rm /path_to_file/TT555.* 
rm /path_to_file/TT666.*
```

I hope my question is clear, I am no programmer that's for sure. Just a guy trying to write a simple script to reduce his daily workflow :) Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure we can solve this, but I can't follow your existing code.  For example, what MESTAID is or how it relates is not clear.

Comment: @John: If I start reading at `for this example ...` I think I understand what user1184129 is asking...

Answer (score 1):

I'd try:

```
echo -n $TTF | xargs -n 1 -d ' ' -I '{}' rm '/path/to/file/TT{}.*'
```

`echo(1)` with `-n` inhibits the newline at the end.

`xargs(1)` with `-n 1` will execute one command at a time, `-d ' '` asks for a space delimiter, `-I '{}'` asks for the replacement of `{}` in the command's initial argument with the standard input elements.

It might be wise to build some small test cases first before dropping this in place; it worked on my simple test case but yours is more involved:

```
$ touch TT111 TT222 TT333
$ echo -n $TTF | xargs -n 1 -d ' ' -I '{}' rm '/tmp/TT{}'
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified version of sarnold's answer:

```
for x in $TTF; do rm /path/to/file/TT$x.*; done
```